# Can I install CyanogenMod in Samsung Galaxy I5510?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom, samsung-galaxy-551

Hello I have a Galaxy I5510 and I''ve reading about ROMS. I'd like to try CyanogenMod but my phone isn't in [the list of supported phones](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices), is there anything I can do?

If not (which I assume) which ROM would you recommend? I'm looking to get extra functionality.

If I don't like some ROM I installed I can uninstall it and go back to the default ROM or any other, right?

Also, I'm kind of scared.. If I get to root my phone without troubles, can installing the ROM break it or my only risk is with the rooting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to try CyanogenMod but my phone isn't in the list of supported phones, is there anything I can do?

If you'd search more carefully, you'd find [this topic (link)](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/27048-samsung-galaxy-551-gt-i5510/). There is CyanogenMod for your phone. But this firmware in early alpha stage of porting. [Another great link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=997436).

> If I don't like some ROM I installed I can uninstall it and go back to the default ROM or any other, right?

Yes, you are right. Also I'd note that there isn't dedicated uninstall procedure, but you always can reflash your phone to another ROM version, including original stock ROM.

> If I get to root my phone without troubles, can installing the ROM break it or my only risk is with the rooting?

The most risky part is, of course, flashing. Because if something goes wrong, you may get bricked phone. But usually everything is OK. Also Android supports recovery boot mode which can help in case of unsuccesful flashing.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'm kind of scared so I'd prefer to wait to a more stable version. Can you suggest me some ROM more stable than those ones for my phone which adds functionality?

Comment: I haven't managed to find any really good custom ROM for this phone. To be honest, I didn't find any custom firmware. I think that reason of it is a little number of owners of this model.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this forum](http://www.madteam.co/forum/forum/). It is dedicated to the development for custom rooted ROMs on GT-I55 series. There are ROMs for I5508, I5500, I5503. Maybe slight modification may port it to I5510. You should ask the dev team for some assistance.